# piping output into middle of bash command

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, piping

Somewhat related to this question: [Convert audio files to mp3 using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255674/convert-audio-files-to-mp3-using-ffmpeg)

I want to execute a command in one line using piping in BASH.

What I am trying to do is this:

```
echo "Hello" | somecommand | ffmpeg -i _____ -f mp2 output.mp3
```

Where the `_____` is the output of `somecommand`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `ffmpeg` supports [libflite](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#flite) which can make audio from text files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using xargs

```
echo "Hello" | somecommand | xargs ffmpeg -f mp2 output.mp3 -i
```

or

```
echo "Hello" | somecommand | xargs -i ffmpeg -i {} -f mp2 output.mp3
```

Comment: xargs -i is my new best friend!

Comment: `xargs -i` is deprecated, use `xargs -I{}`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**command substitution**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) here in the middle argument:

```
ffmpeg -i "$(echo 'Hello' | somecommand)" -f mp2 output.mp3
```

Comment: `somecommand` actually represents the `text2wave` function, so how would I get the output .wav file from that and pass it into ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes same line syntax is what I've shown. It will be: `ffmpeg -i "$(echo 'Hello' | text2wave)" -f mp2 output.mp3 `

Comment: I get an error saying "file name too long" When I run that in terminal. In order to actually save to a .wav file, it has to be done like this: `text2wave -o file.wav`

Comment: Does `text2wave`  writes output on terminal that you want to use in `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: no, text2wave creates an output wav file that I want to use in ffmpeg

Comment: In that case your question was little misleading since pipes are used to pass output of previous command to next command. You can try this command: `ffmpeg -i "$(text2wave -o -)" -f mp2 output.mp3` where `text2wave -o -` will write output on stdout.

Comment: That doesn't work, it just writes all of the wav encoding on to the screen and attempts to use that as a filename..I need the filename of the output file from text2wave

Comment: in that case use it separately but on same line: `text2wave -o file.wav && ffmpeg -i "file.wav" -f mp2 output.mp3`