# Pipe command output inside other command

Tags: json, shell, command, kubectl

I'm trying to pipe the output of the first command into the quotation marks at the end of the second command.

```
kubectl --context foo -n foo get secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -o jsonpath={.data.password}
```

---

```
kubectl --context foo -n foo patch secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -p '{"data":{"password":"    Output from command 1    "}}'
```

I've already tried this: [piping output into middle of bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517390/piping-output-into-middle-of-bash-command), but I get the following error with this command:

```
kubectl --context foo -n foo patch secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -p '{"data":{"`password":"kubectl --context foo -n foo get secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -o jsonpath={.data.password}`"}}'
```

---

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[data:map[`password:kubectl --context foo  -n foo  get secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -o jsonpath={.data.password}`]]": error decoding from json: illegal base64 data at input byte 7
```

Comment: A pipe won't do here. You need [_command substitution_](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixuser/usrosdev/cmd_subst_korn_shell.htm), because one part of your command is supposed to be substituted by the standard output of a different command.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the command in two to make it easier to understand and let the bash shell expand the variable `pgsecret` in the second line:

```
pgsecret="$(kubectl --context foo -n foo get secret \
  postgres.foo-db.credentials -o jsonpath={.data.password})"
kubectl \
  --context foo -n foo patch secret \
  postgres.foo-db.credentials -p '{"data":{"password":"'$pgsecret'"}}'
```

Comment: Are you sure, that your answer is correct? I have tested this and on my environment I received an error. IMO `"'$pgsecret'"` should be only with double quotes: `"$pgsecret"`. Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/605411

Comment: I have no such a problem in a bash environment. The single quotes are stripped by bash.

Comment: Successfully tested with `pgsecret=$(echo "XXX" | base64); kubectl -n myns patch secret testsecret -p '{"data":{"password":"'$pgsecret'"}}'`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of [Davide Madrisan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5721620/davide-madrisan) is good. The code will be more readable. But with this solution you could probably receive an error. In the command:

```
kubectl --context foo -n foo patch secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -p '{"data":{"password":"'$pgsecret'"}}'
```

the reference to a variable `"'$pgsecret'"` is with the double and single quotes. Double are fine, because it must be `"key":"value"` structure. But on my environment single quotes were wrong. I have received an error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '<wrong character>' after object key:value pair
```

You can read more about the difference between `'` and `"` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605411/difference-between-and-in-bash).

I suggest to remove single quotes:

```sh
pgsecret="$(kubectl --context foo -n foo get secret \
  postgres.foo-db.credentials -o jsonpath={.data.password})"
kubectl \
  --context foo -n foo patch secret \
  postgres.foo-db.credentials -p '{"data":{"password":"$pgsecret"}}'
```

or if you want to do this in the one line without a variable (less readable code):

```
kubectl --context foo -n foo patch secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -p '{"data":{"password":"$(kubectl --context foo -n foo get secret postgres.foo-db.credentials -o jsonpath={.data.password})"}}'
```

should also work with you. This treatment is called [`command substitution`](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixuser/usrosdev/cmd_subst_korn_shell.htm), as [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) well mentioned in the comment:

> A pipe won't do here. You need  [*command substitution*](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixuser/usrosdev/cmd_subst_korn_shell.htm), because one part of your command is supposed to be substituted by the standard output of a different command.

Comment: If `pgsecret` contains for instance `WFhYCg==` thant bash will strip the single quotes and pass {"data":{"password":"WFhYCg=="}} to kubectl, which is exactly what you want. Your version will pass `{"data":{"password":"$pgsecret"}` instead and kubectl will complain with the following error message `The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[data:map[password:$pgsecret]]": error decoding from json: illegal base64 data at input byte 0`

Answer (score 0):

backticks (aka $()) are not used as command substitution inside single quotes, but are literal:

```
$ echo '$(echo foo)'
$(echo foo)
```

They are interpolated inside double quotes:

```
$ echo "$(echo foo)"
foo
```

So you just need to properly quote your substitution:

```
$ kubectl --context ... -p '{"data":{"password":"'"$(cmd to get passwd)"'"}}'
```

You could also write:

```
$ kubectl --context ... -p "{\"data\":{\"password\":\"$(cmd to get passwd)\"}}"
```