# Piping output into middle of bash command in 2022

Tags: bash

I am using `oc` command (`kubectl` alternative for Openshift Clusters) to get pods based on a certain condition like this:

```
oc get pods -n mynamespace | awk '/mypod-2022-(.)*/{print $1}'
```

It will give me the following output:

```
mypod-2022-07-01-11-23-driver
mypod-2022-07-02-11-19-driver
...
```

Now for each of the pod names I receive above, I need to execute the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://<my endpoint>/podDelete' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{"POD_NAME": "<output>"}'
```

I tried following the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517390/piping-output-into-middle-of-bash-command), however `xargs -i` does not seem to work in 2022. So is there a way I can substitute `<output>` with each of the lines I receive from `xargs` and run the curl command?

Comment: `xargs -i curl ... '{"POD_NAME": "{}"}'` works fine here.

Comment: _does not seem to work_ is not exactly a helpful error description.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this pipeline with `xargs -I {}`:

```bash
oc get pods -n mynamespace | awk '$1 ~ /^mypod-2022-/{print $1}' |
xargs -I {} curl -X POST 'https://<my endpoint>/podDelete' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  '{"POD_NAME": "{}"}'
```